# siteData parameter in translator web widget

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api, web-widget

I am exploring to add translation widget to our webpages by using [Bing Translator Web Widget API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx). The URL given for the end point (http://www.microsoftTranslator.com/ajax/v3/WidgetV3.ashx?siteData=ueOIGRSKkd965FeEGM5JtQ**) has a siteData parameter which does not seem to be documented anywhere. Can someone point me to an appropriate resource that explains if I need to generate my own siteData parameter? I also need to know if this API subjected to any limits on number of characters translated per month. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following endpoint to generate the widget code:
https://www.bing.com/widget/translator
This will allow you customize the widget in various ways. The site data is an encrypted value that contains the account used when translating. In the past, you could link the widget to your account but this functionality is now deprecated. All new users will now use the default account.

With regards to the limits, there are hourly and daily limits that are applied on a per IP basis to this default account though I am not sure what these exact limits are.